# How to generate a SVG path notation for text

Tags: javascript, google-maps, svg

I have a need to generate SVG path notation for a given number (between 1 and 100).

I need to develop a JavaScript function that will take in a number and return a string that represents the SVG path notation.

Anyone know how to do this?

More context on what I'm working on:

I'm trying to generate a custom symbol to overlay on a polyline, using [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-symbol-custom). You'll notice in the example:

```
  var symbolTwo = {
    path: 'M -1,0 A 1,1 0 0 0 -3,0 1,1 0 0 0 -1,0M 1,0 A 1,1 0 0 0 3,0 1,1 0 0 0 1,0M -3,3 Q 0,5 3,3',
    strokeColor: '#00F',
    rotation: 45
  };
```

There is a path property, which represents the SVG path notation for the [symbol](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Symbol). This needs to follow the [SVG path notation standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathData).

I want to draw numbers on the polylines, so I need a function that can convert a number to a SVG path notation, which I will then set as the symbol on the line.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert text to SVG paths?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742148/how-to-convert-text-to-svg-paths)

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy way to do it. This answer may be what you want:

[How can I create numbered map markers in Google Maps V3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436484/how-can-i-create-numbered-map-markers-in-google-maps-v3/2788519)

Basically use Google's Chart API:

http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=7|FF0000|000000