# Position SVG Font paths within SVG

Tags: php, svg

Im using the script from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/9558337/1755426 to extract paths from svg fonts and then position the text (glyphs) in an svg which I then pull into a PDF. My issue is that the glyphs have their baseline at 0 which is the start of my svg so I only see the descent of the glyph. Ive only just delved into svg due to this and its safe to say Im a bit lost.

Im doing this so that the final PDF will have outlined text and not require embedding fonts into the pdf as this document is to be sent to a printer and most want outline text in artwork as well as not having a whole svg font embedded into my final document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the paths in a group, then use a transform to position them.

```
<g transform="translate(100,200)">
   <path d="..."/>
   <path d="..."/>
   <path d="..."/>
   <path d="..."/>
   <path d="..."/>
</g>
```