# Extracting an SVG path from an SVG font

Tags: javascript, svg, svg-font

I was wondering how easy it is to render path elements extracted from fonts in SVG.

I am aware that .ttf files do not have enough information in them for them to be rendered as path elements in SVG, save only the way to convert them to an image and re-vectorize them using a script, which is...bad and inneficient.

So what would be an ideal way to extract path data directly from SVG fonts?

Is there a way to have a textbox where i type down words using svg fonts and get back the fonts using paths?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742148/how-to-convert-text-to-svg-paths

Comment: @Patrick this is javascript tagged, not php as the question you linked but thanks.

Comment: sorry, missed the tag. nothing in the question listed javascript/node

Comment: Hi, did you find anything?

Comment: @AsimKT https://nodebox.github.io/opentype.js/

Comment: Thanks. My designer friend is creating svg paths for me and he said it is pretty easy.

Comment: @AsimKT This can (with a little modification), extract SVG path data from 'regular' fonts as well `.ttf` etc..