# Trace @font-face text to <svg>

Tags: svg, font-face

We have an SVG teeshirt designer where users can input text using fonts we've provided on the site, however, when these go to the printer they need to be first, part of the `<svg>` itself, and second, converted from `<svg>` to an `.eps` file.

We've got it working, but a big problem seems to be sending the fonts to the printers. It doesn't make sense to have to worry about the printers maintaining all the fonts we're using in our app.

We'd like to somehow "trace" these fonts (think of the Illustrator's `Expand` command used on webfonts) and just send the printer a nice `.eps` and never have to worry about font files.

We were actually using Inkscape to do this with ``--export-text-to-path` and it worked well, but we're migrating to Heroku and Heroku doesn't play nice with Inkscape (at all).

Then I found this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9558337/175825) but the trace it produces isn't always top notch.

I guess my question differs from the [original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742148/how-to-convert-text-to-svg-paths) in that I'm more curious if there's a way to somehow take the `webfont.svg`'s we have and directly pull glyphs from them and replace each letter in the `<tspan>`...

```
<svg>
    <text font-family="MyFont">
        <tspan>Hello!<tspan>
    </text>
</svg>
```

...with that glyph data, positioned somehow.

I know this is a weird question, but I figured a billion heads are better than one. :)